# RecyclerView is not updated when an update occurs in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` where an item can be edited via a `DialogFragment`, so when an item is clicked a `Dialog` is shown, then I can change some properties of that item, the issue is that `RecyclerView` is not updated with the updated properties and I have to force a `notifyItemChanged` when the `Dialog` is closed.

When an item in `RecyclerView` is clicked I set a `MutableLiveData` in my `ViewModel` so then it can be manipulated in the `Dialog`.

My `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DocumentProductsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: DocumentProductsRepository) :
    ViewModel() {
    val barcode = MutableLiveData<String>()

    private val _selectedProduct = MutableLiveData<DocumentProduct>()
    val selectedProduct: LiveData<DocumentProduct> = _selectedProduct

    private val _selectedDocumentId = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    val selectedDocumentId: LiveData<Long> = _selectedDocumentId

    val products: LiveData<List<DocumentProduct>> = _selectedDocumentId.switchMap { documentId ->
        repository.getDocumentProducts(documentId).asLiveData()
    }

    fun insert(documentProduct: DocumentProduct) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(documentProduct)
    }

    fun setProductQuantity(quantity: Float) {
        _selectedProduct.value = _selectedProduct.value.also {
            it?.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            it?.quantity = quantity
        }
        update()
    }

    fun start(documentId: Long?) = viewModelScope.launch{
        if (documentId == null) {
            _selectedDocumentId.value = repository.getHeaderByType("Etichette")?.id
        }

        documentId?.let { documentId ->
            _selectedDocumentId.value = documentId
        }
    }

    fun select(product: DocumentProduct) {
        _selectedProduct.value = product
    }

    fun delete() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _selectedProduct.value?.let { repository.delete(it) }
    }

    private fun update() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _selectedProduct.value?.let { repository.update(it) }
    }
}
```

And in my fragment I'm subscribed to `products` as this:

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {
    binding.rvProducts.adapter = adapter

    viewModel.products.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { products ->
        val productsCount = products.count()
        binding.tvProductsCount.text =
            resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.articoli, productsCount, productsCount)

        // TODO: create amount string and set it with resources
        binding.tvProductsAmount.text = productsCount.toEuro()

        adapter.submitList(products)
        binding.rvProducts.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
    }

    initSwipe(adapter)
}
```

When `setProductQuantity` is called the `RecyclerView` remains unchanged until notify is called while `delete` works fine without the necessity of calling any notify on `RecyclerView`.

**UPDATE:**

The item position is actually changed in RecyclerView as it's sorted by it's last changed timestamp BUT not the quantity field.

Here is my Adapter:

```
class DocumentProductsListAdapter : ListAdapter<DocumentProduct, DocumentProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder>(ProductDiffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_item, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(product)
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val barcode: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.barcode)
        val quantity: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity)
        val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
        val unitOfMeasure: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unitOfMeasure)

        fun bind(product: DocumentProduct) {
            barcode.text = product.barcode
            quantity.text = product.quantity.formatForQta().replace(".", ",")

            if (product.labelType != null && product.labelType != "") {
                unitOfMeasure.text = product.labelType
            } else {
                unitOfMeasure.text = product.unitOfMeasure?.lowercase(Locale.ITALIAN)
            }

            description.text = product.description ?: "-"
        }
    }
}

object ProductDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DocumentProduct>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DocumentProduct, newItem: DocumentProduct): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DocumentProduct, newItem: DocumentProduct): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

```
data class DocumentProduct(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long,
    var barcode: String,
    @Json(name = "desc")
    var description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "PZ")
    @Json(name = "um")
    var unitOfMeasure: String?,
    @Json(name = "qta")
    var quantity: Float,
    @Json(name = "id_testata")
    var documentId: Long,
    @Json(name = "tipo_frontalino")
    var labelType: String?,
    var timestamp: Long?
) {
    constructor(barcode: String, documentId: Long, labelType: String?) : this(
        0,
        barcode,
        null,
        "PZ",
        1f,
        documentId,
        labelType,
        null
    )
 
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return super.equals(other)
    }
 
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return super.hashCode()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've just updated the question with my adapter's code, another strange point is that the position of the item is changed in the recyclerview as the list is sorted by timestamp BUT not the quantity field [example](https://i.gyazo.com/a688fdffdfe6ee978bfd0b4907ee4a6e.gif)

Comment: @Tenfour04 just fixed it but still having the same issue..

Comment: @Tenfour04 oh by setting areContentsTheSame as oldItem.quantity == newItem.quantity works actually, is that the correct way to set it in my case? But it refreshes all the RecyclerView...

Comment: `areContentsTheSame` should be `oldItem == newItem` and `areItemsTheSame` should be `oldItem.id == newItem.id`. Also, the class needs to have proper `equals()`/`hashcode()` implementation that uses all of the properties that are used by the view holder. `data class` is the easiest way to ensure that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 oh I missed the `equals()` and `hashCode()` in my `data class` so overriding them all now works as expected, make an answer about it if you want me to accept it as the solution :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to override `equals()`/`hashcode()` if you use a `data` class because it automatically does it for all properties in the constructor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 without overriding `equals()`/`hashcode()` i still had the same issue where the  items position in the recyclerview was changed but quantity not updated

Comment: @Tenfour04 i've made a pastebin of it [link](https://pastebin.com/PP4qvqS1)

Comment: I see the problem. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the implementations of `areContentsTheSame()` and `areItemsTheSame()` swapped.

`areContentsTheSame()` is asking if everything in the two items being compared is the same. Therefore, if the class has a proper `equals()`/`hashcode()` for all properties used by the ViewHolder, you can use `oldItem == newItem`. If you use a `data class` with all relevant properties in the primary constructor, then you don't need to manually override `equals()`/`hashcode()`.

`areItemsTheSame()` is asking if the two items represent the same conceptual row item, with possible differences in their details. So it should be `oldItem.id == newItem.id`.

The problem with your data class is that you are overriding `equals()`/`hashcode()` without providing any implementation at all. This is effectively **disabling** the proper implementations that are provided by the `data` modifier by calling through to the `super` implementation in the `Any` class. You should not override them at all when you use `data class`.

Comment: The override of `equals()/hashcode()` has been added after my question and without it, I will still have the same issues with the quantity field, so to make `data class` work as it has to I need to add all relevant properties in the primary constructor and only then I can remove the override?

Comment: Yes, that is how `data class` works, but you already have all your properties in the primary constructor. I'm not sure where your issue is, then. If you disable `equals()` by overriding it with  a `super` call, then it's like you're replacing the entire list every time it changes because it thinks every item in the list is changing. This will prevent it from doing nice animations and performance will suffer.

Comment: I can't get where the real problem is as now it's working only with `equals()` overrides with `super` and it's even behaving as it have too without replacing the entire list, check it out [screenrecord](https://i.gyazo.com/30edb0c6a2d216a3fde3ba0ba238121e.gif)

Comment: Oh not actually, in facts it's updating the whole list, but without the quantity is not updated

Comment: Okay I think that I've found the origin of the issue, by calling update from DialogFragment wasn't updating the item quantity in RecyclerView, so I've subscribed to selectedProduct changes in my Fragment and then called .update() in that way it's updating only the interested item